# Как ВК хранит мои логин и пароль?

Tags: cookie

Как вконтакте (и другие крупные интернет-сервисы) хранят мои данные? Я чекал куки, но там нет как в других сервисах обычных куки pass_hash, или чего-либо подобного. И вообще, откуда даже на простых сайтах набирается по 40 куки?

Comment: У каждой куки своё особое предназначение, но логин и пароль (или даже хэш пароля) в куках никто никогда не хранит, потому что это небезопасно

Comment: А никто и не показывает реальные хеш данные и тем более хранить в куках небезопасно - но бывают исключения. Все происходит на сервере, при авторизации, генерится сессионная кука с `uid` адресом, который помещается в куку, но данные сами находятся на сервере и никак не подсмотреть.